# How do I add values to a Python nested list?

Tags: python

How to add values ​​to each list?

before :

```
[['2010', '10', '24', '20', '32', '18', '5'], ['2020', '16', '22', '23', '30', '16', '9'], ['2030', '28', '19', '29', '30', '12', '13']]
```

result : [list] value add ''

```
[['2010', '10', '24', '20', '32', '18', '5', ''], ['2020', '16', '22', '23', '30', '16', '9', ''], ['2030', '28', '19', '29', '30', '12', '13', '']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use for loop,

```
nested_list = [['2010', '10', '24', '20', '32', '18', '5'], ['2020', '16', '22', '23', '30', '16', '9'], ['2030', '28', '19', '29', '30', '12', '13']]

for a_list in nested_list:
    a_list.append('')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do following:

```
my_list = [['2010', '10', '24', '20', '32', '18', '5'], 
           ['2020', '16', '22', '23', '30', '16', '9'],
           ['2030', '28', '19', '29', '30', '12', '13']]

my_list = [inner_list + [''] for inner_list in my_list]
my_list
```

Output:

```
[['2010', '10', '24', '20', '32', '18', '5', ''],
 ['2020', '16', '22', '23', '30', '16', '9', ''],
 ['2030', '28', '19', '29', '30', '12', '13', '']]
```